# How can I monitor the number of outgoing WCF requests?

Tags: wcf

We're trying to track down some performance issues with an application and would like to figure out how many outgoing requests are being triggered by each page load.  I can find lots of counters for showing incoming WCF connections, but nothing tracking how many are going out.  Any ideas short of retrofitting all of the pages with custom counters?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and use the [Trace View Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) or you could go lower level and use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor the outgoing network activity.

Comment: I'm pretty sure tracing only monitors incoming requests and their outgoing responses but does not monitor outgoing requests to downstream services. Wireshark may be the only option.